# Overriding Other Extension's Plugins

Tags: magento2, extensions, plugin

I am building a site that requires the use of a 3rd party extension.

The extension in question is made up of plugins, utilising the `afterToHtml()` Product View methods.

I need to modify these plugins to suit the requirements of the site. Both the 3rd party extension and mine are in `app/code/...`.

Is there a clean way to do this? I am trying my best not to modify someone else's work!

**More Info:**

The plugin that I want to override is adding dynamic HTML to the product view page. Here is the plugin (minus the extension and vendor names):

```
<plugin name="Vendor_Module::Addstatus" type="vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\Status" />
```

And the PHP:

```
public function afterToHtml(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $subject,
    $result
) {
    $name = $subject->getNameInLayout();

    if ( in_array($name, array('product.info.configurable', 'product.info.simple', 'product.info.type_schedule_block6', 'product.info.bundle',  'product.info.virtual',  'product.info.downloadble')) ) {
        $status = $this->_helper->getCustomStockStatusText($subject->getProduct());
        if ($status) {
            $tmp = $this->_helper->showStockStatus($subject->getProduct(), 1, 0);
            if ($tmp != '') {
                $result  = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }

    return  $result;
}
```

I have also corrected the above method. I had it as `beforeToHtml()`, I meant `afterToHtml()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create plugin for same `type` class available in third-party extension in your custom module and write `beforeBeforeToHtml()` method.

ex:

```
public function beforeBeforeToHtml() 
{
  /*
   * content goes here
   */
}
```

This will call your plugin method first.

Comment: Haha! Pluginception! This is good info but, unfortunately, will not serve my needs. The other extension's plugin will still run after mine and undo all of my hard work! Unless... Would `aroundAfterToHtml()` work?

Comment: Yes `aroundAfterToHtml()` will work your need.

Comment: Brilliant! I have moved away from this part of the project, I will be back to test your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options and depends of information that you would like to change:

OP#1 you can create an afterPlugin() of for same method and change the result

OP#2 yo can create a new beforePlugin this is valid a public method could have as many plugins as developers creates on their modules, so what defines the order of execution? well in plugin.xml there is an option "sortOrder" lower has priority if not specified 0 is default value.

here you can find more information about plugins:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Hope this information helps you.

Comment: If I use OP#1, can I switch out the HTML added by the other extension? Does the original HTML (before any plugin affects it) get passed on to the `afterPlugin`?
With OP#2, how would I stop the other plugin from executing after mine? 

I will put more info in my question about the plugins.

Comment: you can't stop plugins execution, magento use this design pattern to avoid problems when manipulating information for a public method.

afterPlugin will have the result of modification from all beforePlugins and afterPlugins(from other modules if exists), but in my experience working with plugins, 'beforePlugin' changes method's params and afterPlugin can be used to change result.

if you want to avoid plugin execution a quick and polite solution could be, create your custom plugin and disable module's plugin (in di.xml file) and document it for futures updates.